# ODE methods with one evaluation per time step and more state

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

[Predictor-corrector method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictor-corrector_method)
gives a "Predict–Evaluate–Correct" method for stepping
$y' = F(y)$ (autonomous)
with one evaluation of $F()$ per time step, and state $[y, step]$:

```
p = y + old step  # predict, look ahead
pstep = h F( p )
step = (old step + pstep) / 2
y += step
```

Are there variants of this with more state, e.g. the last 3 or 4 steps and psteps, but with only one evaluation of $F()$ per time step, along the lines:

```
p = linear function of state
pstep = h F( p )
y, state = linear function of state and pstep
```

As an engineer, not a mathematician, I'd be more interested in
running examples of such methods, with code or pseudocode, 
than in convergence proofs.

(Background:
gradient descent with Nesterov momentum is of the form at the top,
with $p = y + m\  \times$ old step, $m$ a "momentum" factor a bit less than 1; see
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145155/intuition-for-gradient-descent-with-nesterov-momentum)
.)

Comment: You can use previously stored values for $y'_{n-1},y'_{n-2},\ldots,y'_{n-k}$ to do a better interpolation in the corrector step and still maintain one-evaluation-per-step. See e.g. [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-103/S0025-5718-1968-0226865-4/S0025-5718-1968-0226865-4.pdf) for relevant formulas (Eq. 2.3)

Comment: @Winther, thanks; would you know if anyone has used such in practice ?

Comment: I don't know. They were probably used more in the old days when computers were slower making one-eval per step more important. These days Runge-Kutta methods are mostly used as far as I know. It probably has applications still for cases where the evaluation of $F$ is really expensive. Anyway this is just my guess.